# Return ids that are not present in response

Tags: mysql

I want to select all rows that are not found in `IN` where clause

```
CREATE TABLE actions
(
    id integer
);
INSERT INTO actions (id)
VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9);

SELECT * FROM actions
WHERE id in (1,2,3, 12, 14)
ORDER BY id DESC
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b10e1f/1)

In this example, I want to get only the 12 and 14 values, because they are listed in the where clause, but are not present in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values list in the `WHERE IN` clause is not a set.

You must convert it to a rowset (subquery, CTE, temptable).

For example:

```
SELECT id
FROM ( SELECT 1 id UNION
       SELECT 2 UNION
       SELECT 3 UNION 
       SELECT 12 UNION
       SELECT 14 ) params 
LEFT JOIN actions USING (id)
WHERE actions.id IS NULL
```